# Step into a Function through a Function Handle in Matlab debugger

Tags: matlab

I have the following code in an .m file:

```
% define function
fcn = @(x) objfcn(x,pshape,pmean,pstdd,pmask,pmaskinv,pfix,lubound,Y,X); % 
it's function handle for objfcn()

check = 0;
while check<1    
    paraold = mvnrnd(paraest, cc*sigscale,1)';
    paraold = paraold.*pmaskinv + pfix.*pmask;
    [postold, likeold] = fcn(paraold); 
    if postold > -1E6
        check = 1;
    end
end
```

Is there a way that I can step into the function `objfcn.m`? I have tried to put a breakpoint right before the line `[postold, likeold] = fcn(paraold);`, but when I pressed the button "step in" I was brought to the top of the file.

Comment: Put the breakpoint inside 'objfcn' function

Comment: Why didn't I think of that earlier...